# Caret rfe varImp: scaled variable imprtance for rfe results

Tags: r, feature-selection, caret, importance

I want to plot the scaled variable importance of a rfe object (recursive feature elimination). With the following code I compute the rfe model and the variable importance:

```
library(caret)

dat <- as.data.frame(ChickWeight)
all_preds <- dat[,which(names(dat) %in% c("Time", "Chick", "Diet"))]
response <- dat[,which(names(dat) == "weight")]
sizes <- c(1:(ncol(all_preds)-1))

contr <- caret::rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="repeatedcv", number=3, repeats=5, 
                           saveDetails = TRUE)

# recursive feature elimination caret 
results <- caret::rfe(x = all_preds, 
                      y = response,
                      sizes = sizes, 
                      method ="rf",
                      ntree = 250, 
                      metric= "RMSE", 
                      rfeControl=contr)

rfe_imp_scaled <- varImp(results, scale = TRUE)
rfe_imp_notscaled <- varImp(results, scale = FALSE)
```

But there is no difference between `rfe_imp_scaled` and `rfe_imp_notscaled`. How can I get the scaled variable importance of a rfe object?